# How to change the theme and language of syntax highlighting in reveal.js

Tags: css, syntax-highlighting, reveal.js, highlight.js

I'm trying to use the syntax highlighting for a presentation in reveal.js, but I don't want to use zenburn (the default) and I want to highlight code written in R.  I used highlight.js to produce css customized for R but the issue is that highlight.js denotes code in html with 'hljs' while reveal.js uses 'pre code.'  For example highlight.js css looks like:

```
.hljs {
  display: block;
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background: #fdf6e3;
  color: #657b83;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}
```

While reveal.js highlighting css looks like:

```
pre code {
  display: block; padding: 0.5em;
  background: #3F3F3F;
  color: #DCDCDC;
}
```

Can reveal generate alternate themes for syntax highlighting, or is the solution to go through and change all the selectors?

Answer (score 3):

You may be working on an outdated version of reveal.js that is affected by this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/issues/916).

In this case (and if you cannot upgrade) you would replace the inlined minified version of highlight (in `plugin/highlight/highlight.js`) by the latest stable version.

In all other cases just add the desired higlight css file (e.g. idea.css) to lib/css and replace the zenburn.css link in `index.html` (by e.g. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/css/idea.css">`)

Expect that `.reveal pre code` in reveal's theme css may interfere with some highlight styles so they may be hard to read or look bad without further modifications.

Comment: Thanks, I have inlined the information and removed the links. I have also clarified that current reveal.js versions do not require this workaround.

Comment: Links themselves are not bad, but you've to explain the core of the solution in the answer in a way, that it would be useful even without links. Links tend to rot, and when that happens, your answer would be worth of nothing without the links.